# weird NullPointerException in Android 3.0

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-3.1-honeycomb

I don't know the reason why the same code runs OK on Android 2.3 but when it comes to android 3.1 tablet, it throws NullPointerExceptions...here's the code:

```
public class CalleeButton extends Button implements OnClickListener, AddressAware {
private AddressText mAddress;
private OnClickListener externalClickListener;
public void setExternalClickListener(OnClickListener e) {externalClickListener = e;}
public void setAddressWidget(AddressText a) {a=mAddress;}

//set Uri SipUri ,so we can initialize the mAddress inside calleebutton --smartclassroom
//because every calleebutton will have one sip account/ext. this will replace the information for original mAddress --smartclassroom
public void setSip(String StudentName,String SipUri, AddressText a)
{
    Log.i("CalleeButton-35");
    super.setText(StudentName);
    //mAddress.setText(SipUri);
    Log.i("CalleeButton-38");
    mAddress.setContactAddress(SipUri, StudentName);
    Log.i("CalleeButton-40");
    setAddressWidget(a);
    Log.i("CalleeButton-42");

}

public CalleeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOnClickListener(this);

    //must use this line or you got null pointer exception...smartclassroom
    Log.i("CalleeButton-50");
    mAddress = new AddressText(context, attrs);
    //mAddress = null;
    Log.i("CalleeButton-52");
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        if (!LinphoneManager.getInstance().acceptCallIfIncomingPending()) {
            if (mAddress.getText().length() >0) { 
            LinphoneManager.getInstance().newOutgoingCall(mAddress);
                //add new action here
                /*******************************************************/
                /*******************************************************/
            }
        }
    } catch (LinphoneCoreException e) {
        LinphoneManager.getInstance().terminateCall();
        onWrongDestinationAddress();
    };

    if (externalClickListener != null) externalClickListener.onClick(v);
}


protected void onWrongDestinationAddress() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext()
            ,String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.warning_wrong_destination_address),mAddress.getText().toString())
            ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}


}
```

Actually I got NullPointerException on Android 2.3 Platform once, but after adding:

```
mAddress = new AddressText(context, attrs);
```

then it compiles and runs smoothly...until I try to install the same program on android 3.1 tablet...weird, isn't it ? Please let me learn what mistakes I have made on this, thanks in advance!  the error msgs for logcat are:

```
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.linphone/org.linphone.LinphoneActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.linphone/org.linphone.DialerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.linphone/org.linphone.DialerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1592)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:130)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:342)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:676)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:345)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TabHost.java:282)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at org.linphone.LinphoneActivity.gotToDialer(LinphoneActivity.java:481)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at org.linphone.LinphoneActivity.fillTabHost(LinphoneActivity.java:207)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at org.linphone.LinphoneActivity.onCreate(LinphoneActivity.java:126)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     ... 11 more
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at org.linphone.DialerActivity.onCreate(DialerActivity.java:128)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
04-25 23:58:13.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6728):     ... 22 more
```

From my opinion,the logcat msgs told me about the function:

```
    mCallee1.setSip("Jack","sip:xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",mAddress);
```

in DailerActivity.java(which you can treat it as main function here) caused the NullPointerExcetion, then I trace the code to CalleeButton.java, but still can't get find the point where caused the null pointer exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on that line (`setSip()`), and check the mCallee1 and mAddress variables. One should be null. That will be your problem. Then just trace it back and find out why it isn't being instantiated -- or if null is a valid state for the variable, just check it for null before calling `setSip()`.

Comment: after setup the exception breakpoint, then I debug with eclipse. I found that the value of variable mCallee1 is null. I can't find out the reason why... variable type of mCallee1(which is CalleeButton) is very similar to variable type of mCall(which is CallButton). I tried many different ways try to get around it, but the value is still the same, null...

Comment: Edit in the code where you are running into this. You don't have anything involving an `mCallee1` variable in what's posted.

Comment: I found it!!! it's because my layout problem. My android 3.0 tablet only uses landscape layout which I ignored to initialize those xml layout files.